# Xamarin: StaticResource: No property, bindable property or event for 'FontSize'?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

so i am trying to design a little login page, based on this tutorial:
[Xamarin Tutorial](https://www.kymphillpotts.com/social-network-app-layout-design-in-xamarin-forms/)

My code differs a little, this is my LoginPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.ViewModels.LoginPage"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}">
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--header spacing-->
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Image Source="LoginBackground.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="150"/>
            <Image Source="CurvedLimiter.png" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="Fill"/>

            <!--header-->
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="100"/>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <Entry Text="Email" x:Name="Email" Style="{StaticResource LoginEntry}"/>
                <Entry IsPassword="True" Text="Password" x:Name="Password" Style="{StaticResource LoginEntry}"/>
                <Button Text="Login" x:Name="btnLogin" Clicked="btnLogin_Clicked" Style="{StaticResource LoginButton}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!--login-->
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

As you can see, I am using StaticRessources, which are described in my App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- colors -->
            <Color x:Key="HeaderTextColor">#585858</Color>
            <Color x:Key="BodyTextColor">#C3C3C3</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor">#5992FF</Color>
            <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">#5992FF</Color>

            <!--Font families-->
            <OnPlatform x:Key="RegularFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="HelveticaNeue" Android="sans-serif" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="LightFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="HelveticaNeue-Light" Android="sans-serif-light" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="MediumFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="HelveticaNeue-Medium" Android="sans-serif-medium" />

            <!-- Font sizes -->
            <Font x:Key="BodyFont" FontSize="18" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" />
            <Font x:Key="TagTextFont" FontSize="18" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" />
            <Font x:Key="StatsNumberFont" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource LightFontFamily}" />
            <Font x:Key="StatsCaptionFont" FontSize="16" FontFamily="{StaticResource LightFontFamily}" />
            <Font x:Key="ButtonFont" FontSize="14" FontFamily="{StaticResource MediumFontFamily}" /> 

            <!-- Styles -->
            <Style x:Key="LoginEntry" TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="LoginButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFont}"/>
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ProfileNameLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TitleFont}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ProfileTagLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BodyTextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TagTextFont}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="StatsNumberLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource StatsNumberFont}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="StatsCaptionLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BodyTextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-5,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource StatsCaptionFont}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="MainBodyLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BodyTextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource BodyFont}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="FollowButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFont}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The thing is that this worked, at least in the XAML preview. However when I wanted to compile the code, I got the following error message, which refers to the first Font x:key=... Line:

> Position 19:36. No property, bindable property, or event found for
>   'FontSize', or mismatching type between value and property.

Why is it? Now also the XAML previewer doesn't work anymore, because the project failed to compile...

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: <Font x:Key="BodyFont" FontSize="18" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" />
Pretty sure this should be x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Value="18"

Comment: Thanks for the hint: When I write the following:
<Font x:Key="BodyFont" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Value=18" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" />
The compiler just tells me that 'Value' is not a Property of Font.
Also, the FontSize property worked at least in the XAML Previewer..

Comment: Addition: I just had a look at the Font struct itself. It does hold a "FontSize" Attribute.

Comment: Addition 2: If I delete all the FontSize attributes from <Font ... , the next error is that the compiler doesn't know "FontFamily"...

Comment: It's because you are doing it wrong. You should do it in a similar fashion you done Buttons. I'll write in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your fonts wrong.

```
            <Style x:Key="BodyFont" TargetType="Label">
             <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
             <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}"/>
            </Style>
```

And do the same for rest of the fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sounds good, copied it 1:1 in my app.xaml, however it doesnt work. On compilation I receive the following error: "Can't resolve Fontsize on Font"..?

Comment: Sorry it should be Label not font.

Comment: Thanks, however this then seems to be something different to what I initially tried to do. I wanted do define a generic font which could then be used in different TargetTypes.